# Embedded systems toolkit to learn and practice on my own

Tags: embedded

I am from computer science background and  planning to learn embedded systems. I have more than enough materials to study, but i have no idea on how to practice it.Please tell me, 
If there is any emulator or toolkit available to learn and practice Embedded Systems and it's concepts in-depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of choices, out of which I found these few interesting:

- [MSP430 LaunchPad Value Line Development kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430g2) - very affordable and very limited
- [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) - open source hardware, strong community

Note - I did not use the above, I played with [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller) a long time ago - if you are interested in PICs, check this out:

- http://www.picaxe.com/

There's one that is a bit bigger:

- [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)

in the sense that it runs Linux and has HDMI output - this is more if you are software-oriented than hardware-oriented.

Here's a good overview (though a bit dated) of the options and some considerations:

- http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-choose-a-MicroController/?ALLSTEPS